# Universal link doesn't work preperly in Instagram webview

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I implemented a universal link for app and it works properly when I call it from Apple Notes, slack and etc, but it can't open the app when it is called from a link in Instagram, what should I do?

the AASA is

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "XXXXXXX.XXX.XXXXXX",
                    "XXXXXXX.XXX.XXXXXX.beta"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/l/*",
                        "comment": "Universal links for stores."
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/reservation*",
                        "comment": "Universal links for reservation in previous configuration."
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/store*",
                        "comment": "Universal links for stores in previous configuration.."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: The temporary solution: when you try to call the universal link within a new blank page, the HTML code forces the Instagram browser to open it in Safari and the problem is solved, but the user must press the button.